# How to get random page of specific "Portal:" using WikiMedia API

Tags: api, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, wikimedia

Is there any way to get random article of specific wikimedia portal using wikimedia API?

For example, I need random page of [Portal:Science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal%3aScience).

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're asking for doesn't make much sense, because a portal doesn't have a list of pages associated with it.

The closest thing you can do is to get a random page from e.g. [`Category:Science`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aScience) or one of its subcategories. There is no way to do that directly using the API, you would need to traverse all the subcategories and choose a random page from them by yourself.

There is a tool that already does this (with a limit on the depth of the category tree): [erwin85's random article](http://toolserver.org/~erwin85/randomarticle.php) and [there is also a template for it on the English Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3aRandom_page_in_category).

Comment: How to retrieve a random page from Category:Science ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:RandomInCategory/Science will give you random pages in that category